# Wanted to override initEvents of Scrollbar module in highcharts using stock.js and highcharts.js

Tags: highcharts, scrollbar, stock

I wanted to override initEvents of Scrollbar module but am not getting this module after loading highcharts.js, stock.js of version - 8.2.2

Comment: Hi @Purva Kshatriya, Could you describe the problem more precisely?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, I found the solution, initially I was using highstock.js Now used stock.js and was able to override functions - initEvents. Thanks